# rsync style knife upload of Chef Cookbooks in Git post-receive hook

Tags: chef-infra, knife, git-post-receive

I would like to `knife upload` in a post-receive hook of a cookbook repository.  However, we have too many cookbooks to simply upload all of them anytime a change is made.

Is there a way to `knife upload` only changed cookbooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have all your cookbooks in the same repo. You can use `git diff` to determine the changes between HEAD and the previous commit and knife upload those results.

```
git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 | awk -F '/' '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq | xargs -I % knife cookbook upload %
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `berks upload` it will automatically skip anything where the current version is already uploaded.